# Unable to locate checkbox Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

i am trying to make my selenium script select the "selectALL" checkbox on a website. The trouble is the python program **cannot find it**

I have tried

- Using name
- Using xpath

Results are as follows.

With name:

```
checkButton = driver.find_element_by_name("checkALL")
checkButton.click()

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[name="checkALL"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

With xpath:

```
checkButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//table[@id='tbl2']/tbody/tr/td/input")
checkButton.click()

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//table[@id='tbl2']/tbody/tr/td/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.132)
```

Google Chrome element dump:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkALL" rownumber="" value="notchecked" onclick="checkAllCheckedRows('portID')">
```

I'm very confused as to why this is not working. I even have a 5 second delay between actions.

**Full Code**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("http://192.168.1.235/login.cgi")
assert "NETGEAR ProSAFE Plus Switch" in driver.title
#Locate Password
passwordInput = driver.find_element_by_id("password")
#Input switch password
passwordInput.clear()
passwordInput.send_keys("password")
passwordInput.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#Wait for mainpage to load
time.sleep(5)
#Switch to Port Status
portStatusButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="blueLinkBold11"]/div[2]/a')
print(portStatusButton)
portStatusButton[0].click()
time.sleep(5)
#Check select all checkbox
checkButton = driver.find_element_by_name("checkALL")
checkButton.click()
#Select option from Menu (Disable)
speedDropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("SPEED"))
speedDropdown.select_by_value(2)
#Click Apply Button
applyButton = driver.find_element_by_name("btn_Apply")
applyButton.click()
driver.close()
```

Comment: Make sure you wait until the page is loaded and element is displayed. And also check if the element is present in the iframe.

Comment: @supputuri it certainly has loaded and displayed. Still it does not work

Comment: Were you able to find the element with `[name='checkALL']` in the chrome devtools?

Comment: @supputuri yes i could

Comment: now check `[name='checkALL']/ancestor::html`. If it's pointing to the browser html then you don't have any iframe wrapping the element but if you see `document#` as parent of the html element then get the iframe and switch to it.

Comment: I don't see document# I see <!DOCTYPE html> [name='checkALL']/ancestor::html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209718/discussion-between-supputuri-and-lyra-orwell).

Answer (score 1):

To click on the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='checkALL'][value='notchecked'][onclick^='checkAllCheckedRows']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='checkALL' and @value='notchecked'][starts-with(@onclick, 'checkAllCheckedRows')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I get a raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace) error

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch to the right iframe before interacting with the element.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_css_selector(css_selector))
# then click on the element.
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[name='checkALL']"))).click()
```